# how to used Serialport in my AM1808 ARM9

Tags: qt, arm, qt5, embedded-linux

I update qt 4.8.4 to qt 5.1.0 
and change the required modules as described in the change over document supplied by Qt.

We test the new compiler with our current code, that has a UART interface with an external device.

For that, we were running an external serial port library named qextserialport in old compiler qt 4.8.4.

In current case with qt 5.1.0,

how do I use the serial port library as my old library is not supported in current qt version?

Is there any serial port library available in this new version or need to use an external library and how to install and use it??

Answer (score 0):

QSerialPort should work fine. It is supported since Qt 5.1